# Tensorflow: Train pre-trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does anybody know how to train a pre-trained model from Tensorflow zoo?
I have tried to use different models and different tf versions (1.8-1.11).

Eventually I come to an error similar to this one:

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key Conv/biases/Momentum not
>   found in checkpoint    [[Node: save/RestoreV2 =
>   RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0,
>   save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

I use a checkpoint right from the model I have just loaded. In the pipelineconfig I update "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" only.

Is it a porblem with the model zoo or with my environment / dataset / tfrecords?

Does anybody have a simple example?

Comment: Can you include the code where you train / load the model?

Comment: Sorry for lack of details. I have added UPDATE.